# Single Sign On(SSO) to Microsoft Bot v4 (WebChat) through Angular webpage

Tags: c#, angular, single-sign-on, botframework

I have a webpage(Angular), which authenticates the user, after login in(oAuth2), the user has an option to interact with the bot (Bot Framework v4 C#) as of now I had the bot Independent, hence had used the OAuthCard in the bot to authenticate the user.

Now I want to have a Single Sign-on. I am not sure how the user token will be passed from the webpage to the bot, I have two scenarios now sure which is the correct one: 
1. Send the user token with every message, requires validation on every message, too much computation. 
2. Send the token with a TTL, and handle the expiry.

But for now, I am not sure how to send the token from the Webpage to the C# App.

I did go through [this](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/08/28/sign-in-experiences/), and as it says

"A third option, called Single Sign-On (SSO), is in development and is where the client UI takes the client’s user token for the client app and exchanges it for a different token that can be used with the same identity provider, but a different app/scopes. For now, it is possible to create a similar user experience using WebChat by using technique #1 above."

And the document seems a bit too sparse to understand how exactly it was done with technique #1

Answer (score 1):

I agree, that blog post is quite confusing and I still have no clue what they're intending to eventually do for what they describe as the "SSO scenario". The major difference they describe there from simply handing the bot the token from the SPA is that they will do some sort of token exchange for a different set of scopes that the bot needs vs the SPA. This would certainly be useful, but, as of right now, it's "all talk" and I'm not aware of anything they've built to enable it.

Let me just address your two points real quick first..

---

> 1. Send the user token with every message, requires validation on every message, too much computation.

First off, I would venture to say that the majority of the web is built on token exchange at this point. Tokens need to be continually passed around, signatures validated and then checked for expiry. This is just the nature of authentication; I don't think this is a bot specific problem.

> 2. Send the token with a TTL, and handle the expiry.

Are you using JWTs? They have TTL built into them via the standard `exp` claim, so you shouldn't need to worry about inventing your own TTL. Yes, you do need to check for expiry.

---

Ok, that said, if you're concerned with the overhead of constantly passing the token to the bot, you can choose to send it once via a custom, "backchannel" event over the DirectLine connection. Your bot can then take this token, validate it once and associate it with the conversation state so that the client need not send it on every request. Keep in mind however, you will still need to continually validate the token has not expired.

This backchannel event and the handling of it would be completely proprietary (e.g. there is nothing in the box to do this for you today). Just like you would have an event from the client to the bot to send the token in, you can also have an event that goes from the bot to the client to tell it it needs a token from the client (e.g. first request, or refreshed one because of expiry).